# Is it possible to invoke Thor commands from my Web App?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, thor

Some time ago, I wrote a few command line applications using Ruby with the Thor gem. Now, I need to create a web interface for using exactly the same functionality existing in these CLI's. Is it possible to call Thor commands from the web app without appealing to things like `%x{}`, `exec()` and `system`? Is there something more programatic like `MyClass.invoke(:command, arg1, arg2, option1: '', option2: '')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
MyClass.start(args, config)
```

args is an array of strings that represent the options you would pass on the command line, config is a hash.

```
MyClass.start(["-f", "blah"], type: :yo)
```

You should be able to access the config options within your Thor class like this:

```
config[:type]  # => :yo
```